# tried to recreate the _.once function but only works upon at least 2 iterations not one

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
onceCopy function (testFunc) {
  const copyFunc = (a) => {
    const copyFunc2 = (b) => {
      return testFunc(a);
    };    
    return copyFunc2;
  };
  return copyFunc;
};
```

So the function returns the inner function upon first invocation.

Then returns the inner function of the inner function of the second invocation.

Then the second inner function (third invocation) actually returns the passed argument in the parent function and only invokes it with the character we gave it on the second invocation.

Ideally I want to achieve what I'm achieving over many invocations after only the first one if that makes sense.

Edit: Yes sorry, _.once.

Edit: so first invocation onceCopy SHOULD hold a copy of the Func passed
Second invocation SHOULD trigger the copy and gives an ouput
Third invocation SHOULD give the result of the second invocation so should the fourth, fifth, sixth and so on...

My function does do this, but on the second invocation it stores a function (copyFunc2) again, but I just made that because I need somewhere to store "a".

so like we have

`function multiplyBy3 (a) {return a*3}`
and then once copy stores a copy of multiplyBy3

`const actualFunction = onceCopy(multiplyBy3)`

then upon second and third invocation what I want

actualFunction(1) = 3
actualFunction(66) = 3

so the passed function ONLY RUNS ONCE

Cant explain more than this, its in the lodash docs.

Comment: What is the lodash `_.only` function? Can you link to documentation?

Comment: *"if that makes sense"*: hmmm... can you provide some examples of *calls* you want to make and the expected output for each? I think that would clarify what you want.

Comment: Why isn't the `b` parameter used?

Comment: I can't find `_.only()` in the lodash documentation. Did you mean `_.once()`? But it doesn't seem to be related to what you're doing here (this looks like currying).

Comment: b doesn't need to be used. Answered all Q's in the edits. New to this site.

Comment: it probably looks like currying because I recreated the curry function too and im using what I learnt from that, Im new to code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the function you're trying to reimplement, so feel free to correct me if I misunderstood. To wrap a function and ensure it's only called once you don't need multiple nested wrappings, only one with some state.

You need to keep track of whether you already have a result to return (`hasResult`) and if so, what that result is (`result`). Keeping these two variables separate allows you to cover the case when `result` is `undefined` while keeping the code easy to read and understand.

```js
function once(wrappedFunction) {
  let hasResult = false;
  let result;
  return (...args) => {
    if (hasResult) {
      return result;
    }
    result = wrappedFunction.apply(this, args);
    hasResult = true;
    return result;
  }
}

// An example function to wrap
function multiply(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}

const demoFunction = once(multiply)
console.log(demoFunction(1, 2)); // 2
console.log(demoFunction(3, 4)); // 2
console.log(demoFunction(5, 6)); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

The initial function return is kept on subsequent calls. I used a second variable `called` in case the first call returns undefined, which should also be returned on subsequent calls.

```js
const once = (onceFn) => {
  let called;
  let value;

  return (...args) => {
    if (called) return value;
    called = true;
    return (value = onceFn(...args));
  };
};

function multiplyBy3(a) {
  return a * 3;
}

const fn = once(multiplyBy3);

console.log(fn(3)); // 9
console.log(fn(66)); // 9
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After calling the function for the 1st time, and getting the result, create a new function that returns the result, and use it whenever the wrapped function is called:

```js
const once = fn => {
  let func
  
  return (...args) => {
    if(func) return func()
    
    const result = fn(...args)
    
    func = () => result
    
    return result
  } 
}

const multiply = (a, b) => a * b

const demoFunction = once(multiply)

console.log(demoFunction(1, 2)); // 2
console.log(demoFunction(3, 4)); // 2
console.log(demoFunction(5, 6)); // 2
```

Comment: Hi, so what is let func? I usually use let to declare variables and use the assignment operator "="

Comment: A variable is JS can point to a function. We check if `func` is defined using `if(func)`. If it is we return the result of running `func`. If not, we use the original function to get the result `const result = fn(...args)`, and then we create a function that always returns the result and assign it to `func` - `func = () => result`.

Now that func is defined, we call it each time to return the original result.

Comment: I tried to recreate your solution by memory, and I got this and it still works?

Comment: ```hof.once = function (testFunc) { 
  let func;
  return function function2(...args) {
    if (func) {
      return testFunc(...args);
    }
  };
};```

Comment: or im testing completely wrong. im struggling to wrap my head around the solution though, yours and mine.

Comment: func is defined before it is assigned. You are running func() before we even know what func is doing.

Comment: can you tell me what is happening on the first invocation, the second invocation, and the third invocation of our Once function?

Comment: If func is not defined, this condition would be falsy - `if(func)`, and the then `func` would be assigned. On the 2nd iteration and forwards, `func` would be defined, so `if(func)` would be truthy, and would return the result of calling func. Take my solution and add some `console.log` calls to see the value of func.